# ambiguous column name when using row_number and join

Tags: sql, db2

`Table_1` and `Table_2` both have `id` and `name` columns

This query works:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS rn Table_1.*,
               Table_2.*
          FROM Table_1 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_2 on Table_1.id = Table_2.id
       )
  WHERE rn Between 1 AND 10
```

But how to select the column name in Table_1? I replaced * with Table_1.name, and it shows:

```
SQL0206N  "Table_1.name" is not valid in the context where it is used.  
SQLSTATE=42703
```

Comment: To troubleshoot, take away the table2.*.  If that solves the problem, add just the fields you need, one by one.

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't want to use `SELECT *`, and this can be one of the reasons.  One of the other big ones is that the optimizer may be able to better use indices if it knows exactly which columns you need - if you just ask for all the columns, it'll have to hit the table.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're missing a comma between `rn` and `Table_1`. I think this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS rn
        ,Table_1.*
        ,Table_2.*
    FROM Table_1 
    LEFT JOIN Table_2 
      on Table_1.id = Table_2.id
) A
WHERE rn Between 1 AND 10
```

Comment: I had to add a table identifier, 'AS <someName>' before the WHERE clause/after the final bracket, to get this working, i.e. ') AS myTableName WHERE', just in case that helps somebody....

Comment: Ah yeah, that would make a difference. I updated my answer, thanks @BigRich!

Answer (score 0):

As bhamby said, it looks like you've left out a comma between `rn` and `Table_1`

You might also be able to simplify your query...

```
SELECT x.*, y.*
  FROM Table_1 x
  LEFT JOIN Table_2 y
    on x.id = y.id
  FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```